# Does Craft Have Publishing Workflow?

Tags: control-panel

Is it possible to allow some users to write content & an editor can edit & publish / approve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can give a user or a user group the following permissions (on each section separately):

- Edit entries

  - Create entries
  - Publish live changes
  - Delete entries
  - Edit other authors’ entries
  - Edit other authors’ drafts

If a user only can "create entries", but not "publish live changes", then he is not able to publish an entry (but he can create the entry).

Comment: ok, thanks.  What does "Publish Live Changes" mean then?

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. My answer has been updated after a test on version 2.2.

Comment: ok, i see.  I've got the ontherocks.dev running & tested this.  Makes sense once you know what's happening.  would be great if it notified editors of things to approve etc but is probably good enough for most situations

Answer (score 1):

As MISC has mentioned, Craft has a great permissions system built-in, which allows you to assign users the ability to either *publish* content live, or instead only *create* it and have others publish it.

Here's a screenshot of a typical permissions screen:

[image: Craft CMS Permissions Screen]

To take this to the next level, Josh Crawford has developed a great free plugin called [***Workflow***](https://github.com/engram-design/Workflow) which enhances this with:

- User interface improvements, including a button to "Submit for Review"
- Email notifications to notify publishers that an entry is ready for review
- Entries become locked while they are awaiting review
- Extra events for hooking into the submission/publishing process with additional custom functionality

#### Some screenshots:

[image: Craft Workflow Plugin]

[image]

[image]

[image]

See https://github.com/engram-design/Workflow

Answer (score 1):

This knowledge base article shows how the publishing workflow works in the current version of Craft https://craftcms.com/knowledge-base/editing-entries