# Loading an existing entries drafts in template/frontend

Tags: admin, frontend

I've been searching for a method to load in an existing entries drafts. Here is what I am trying to implement.

User can add or edit an entry from the front end of my craft site. They cannot publish.
Admin can see new drafts and publish them.

I see how to submit a draft update via the front end using the entryRevisions/saveDraft method. But how can I load in the current entries draft information into a form on the front end for a user to edit? Hopefully I missed this, or is it undocumented.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Craft Have Publishing Workflow?](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2533/does-craft-have-publishing-workflow)

Comment: Not a duplicate. That post has absolutely no reference to the draft system or the method I'm looking for.

Comment: Yep right, thought you meant save without publish. Sorry!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After doing some digging around I found the `getDraftsByEntryId(entryId, locale)` method of the `craft.entryRevisions` service that might help.

The following should return the first draft of an entry. Note: there is a second argument for 'locale', which defaults to current locale if none provided. Also not sure whether 'first' or 'last' would be considered the most recent draft.

```
{% set drafts = craft.entryRevisions.getDraftsByEntryId(entry.id) %}
{% if drafts|length %}
    {% set draft = drafts[0] %}
    {{ draft.title }}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

You will need to load the entry manually (i.e. through a custom route of some kind) as the draft's entry is likely to be 'disabled' (although not necessarily) and thus not load through the entry's default url. Something like '/mysection/edit/slug' perhaps (where 'slug' is a custom route token).

```
{% set entry = craft.entries({
    section: 'mysection',
    slug: slug
    status: null
}).first() %}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Not sure how I missed that method, but thanks for the help.