# Entry publishing workflow

Tags: entries, users, permissions, workflow

I am considering using Craft to develop a website for a client.
One of the requirements is that members have access tot he backend to edit a single entry.

Here is the use case:

1. entry is created manually by admins, unpublished
2. members are in a group with "editEntries:[SectionID]" permission only (no create, delete and others)
3. members edit their entry and submit for review/approval
4. admins publish the entry
5. members come back and edit the entry if necessary and submit for review/approval of changes
6. admin reviews changes and amend or approves the changes

The question is what would be the best way to achieve the following:

When a member comes back, edits and submits the entry (step 5), it create a new revision for review/approval by admins (step 6), **but keeps the current revision published in the frontend**.

Any thoughts on how to achieve this?

Comment: See a similar question here: *[Does Craft Have Publishing Workflow?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/2533/5437)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a mixture of the permissions you mention above and user groups, you should be able to use the [Workflow](https://github.com/engram-design/Workflow) plugin to get the results you are looking for.

Comment: I did see that indeed - I would go and test it if I could, except that I won't be able to buy the multi-users license unless I am sure this critical feature can be handled. As far as I saw, the Workflow plugin's wiki doesn't say anything about the previous revision being still shown in the frontend when an existing entry has been edited. I see "As the entry is disabled, your entry will not be publicly visible." though. Do you personally have experience with the specific use case in the OP? It may help me greatly to get directions.

Comment: Tested and works. There are some possibly confusing parts for publishers between a draft entry, a published entry and an approved draft entry - it could be more straightforward. For example, an option when Approving a draft entry to publish it directly would be nice.

Comment: https://github.com/engram-design/Workflow/issues/17